# Django Migration Error with PostGIS: 'double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: django, django-settings, django-postgresql

I am developing a web application using Django and encountering a critical issue during database migration with PostGIS. While migrations work seamlessly with the SpatiaLite engine, switching to the PostGIS engine leads to a crash. The error message I receive is: "double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)". This issue arises specifically when I attempt to make migrations with the PostGIS engine.

My Django project settings for the database are as follows:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'geodesia_interoperable',
        'USER': 'depiction',
        'PASSWORD': '************',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}



I have verified that PostgreSQL and PostGIS are correctly installed and configured, and the database credentials are accurate. The application runs as expected with SpatiaLite but fails when switched to PostGIS.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have insights into what might be causing this error with PostGIS in Django? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.
```